# How to make sure two requests were send in different time?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

I need to send many requests to server, but I have to make sure they were send in different time or I will be banned from the server, this is what I do:

```
lock(_lock)
{
     SendRequest();
     Sleep(100);
}
```

But the problem is, the thread will always delay for 0.1 seconds, is there a more efficient way?　　ps. there's no respond from the server

Added:
I figure out another way, but the code is a little complex

```
autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

SendRequest();

new Thread(() =>
{
     Thread.Sleep(100);
     autoResetEvent.Set();
}).Start();
```

Comment: If you have to throttle, you have to throttle. If you don't want to block the thread, you can try going async, but if you do then you need to go async-all-the-way ( use something like `await SendRequestAsync(); await Task.Delay(100);`. If you use Task.Run you just use another (Threadpool-)Thread. Tbh, I don't think it will help much. The server is your bottleneck here and you are already using a Thread to not block your UI, right?

Comment: @Fildor You are right, the UI thread won't be blocked in my code, but the other threads need to do some not-so-important work after SendRequest(), so the less waiting is always better.

Comment: Are you familiar with async/await?